# Rand Index to compare two different labels' size

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I want to compare two partitions using Adjusted Rand Index.
The first partition contains n clusters separated(no-overlap).
The 2nd contains m clusters overlapped.
When an element exists in 2 different clusters, I count it twice and give it two different indices. That cannot be applied to ARI.

This illustration is intended to make the problem clearer :
Let S and P be 2 partitions where :

```
S={CLUSTER1, CLUSTER2} 
CLUSTER1={A,B}
CLUSTER2={C}
```

The indices'vector associated to S is : `V1=[1,1,2]`

```
P={Group1, Group2, Group3}
Group1={A}
Group2={A,B}
Group3={B,C}
```

The indices'vector associated to P is : `V1=[1,2,2,3,3]`
That of course won't work. Because beyond the problem of sizing, there is no order.
Do you have ideas about this problems resolution ?
I am thinking about testing S with P' and S with P" ... where P' is a partition that looks a bit like P but where there is no overlap. For example : `P'=[{}, {A,B}, {C}]`

Comment: If youre just guessing to compare, its probably not the greatest performance. But if for some reason you have to then, good luck :)

Comment: Could you please tell me why you think it's not the greatest one ? Do you have any suggestions ? My objective is to compare two partitions where one contains overlaps

Comment: Yes, do not guess in these types of equations. My assumption is that your best language is not English :)

Comment: Think 1 / 2 ? = Random ? No.

Comment: 1 / 2 = 0.5
Reduce it to the most minimal "Big O" value.

Comment: "Big O" = Runtime computation value of computers.

Comment: It is dumb, make no sense. But, it make sense if you really think : )

Comment: Partitions of Hard Drive?

Comment: Message me. That s some other

Comment: I don't think these methods can easily be adapted to overlapping partitionings. This will always create some bias. Even if you get the Rand index itself to work by averaging, the adjustment for chance likely won't work anymore. What is a "by chance" result with overlap?